# Overlapping functionality of DependencyProperties and RoutedEvents

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, dependency-properties

I'm still getting into WPF and MVVM. I have written a `ColorPicker` control which is based on my primitve control `ColorPickerBase` which is a colorWheel with a picker thumb.

The `ColorPickerBase` essentially looks like this (heavily cut to save space):

```
public class ColorPickerBase : Control
{
    #region Dependency Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorPickerBase));

    public Color SelectedColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); UpdateThumbPosition(); }
    }
    #endregion // Dependency Properties

#region EventHandlers
    public delegate void ColorChangedEventHandler(object sender, Color newColor);
#endregion EventHandlers

    #region Routed Events
    public static readonly RoutedEvent SelectedColorChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("SelectedColorChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(ColorChangedEventHandler), typeof(ColorPickerBase));   

    public event ColorChangedEventHandler SelectedColorChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(SelectedColorChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(SelectedColorChangedEvent, value); }
    }
    #endregion //Routed Events

    static ColorPickerBase()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorPickerBase), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorPickerBase)));
    }

    #region Event Overrides
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        mColorThumb.DragDelta += OnColorThumbDragDelta;
    }
    #endregion //Event Overrides

    #region Events
    private void OnColorThumbDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        //some calculations
        SelectedColor = Color.FromRgb(pixel[2], pixel[1], pixel[0]);
        // Trying to raise SelectedColorChanged here.
    }


    #endregion //Events
}
```

In my `ColorPicker` class, I have an instance of `ColorPickerBase` and add a handler to `SelectedColorChanged`

```
[TemplatePart(Name="PART_ColorSpectrum", Type = typeof(Controls.Primitives.ColorPickerBase))]
public class ColorPicker : Control
{
    #region Private Fields
    private Primitives.ColorPickerBase mColorSpectrum;
    #endregion //Private Fields

    #region Properties
    public Byte R
    {
        get { return mColorSpectrum.SelectedColor.R; }
        set { mColorSpectrum.SelectedColor = Color.FromArgb(mColorSpectrum.SelectedColor.A, value, mColorSpectrum.SelectedColor.G, mColorSpectrum.SelectedColor.B); }
    }
    public Byte G
    ...
    public Byte B
    ...
    #endregion //Properties

    #region Constructor
    static ColorPicker()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorPicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorPicker)));
    }

    public ColorPicker()
    {

    }
    #endregion //Constructor

    #region Event Overrides
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        mColorSpectrum = GetTemplateChild("PART_ColorSpectrum") as Primitives.ColorPickerBase;
        mColorSpectrum.SelectedColorChanged += OnSelectedColorChanged;
    }
    #endregion //Event Overrides

    #region Event Handlers
    void OnSelectedColorChanged(object sender, Color newColor)
    {
        R = newColor.R; G = newColor.G; B = newColor.B;
    }
    #endregion //Event Handlers
}
```

Now, from my understanding, DependecyProperties have this exact feature already implemented under the name of NotifyPropertyChanged. I now wonder how I could use that feature in the owning class `ColorPicker`.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is probably what you want. Implementing that interface gives you a `PropertyChanged(string)` event signature which the binding system will listen to (unless I've misunderstood the question :)) - if you are wondering how to wire up the inner to the outer, the way you've already done it is fine

Comment: `SelectedColor` was a DependencyProperty to begin with (for binding in the Control Template) I'm just not sure how to use the NotifyPropertyChanged feature in the "owning" class. Do I need to derive the `ColorPicker` class from `INotifyPropertyChanged` (i.e. the recieving end) or the other one. Maybe you could write or link a quick example?

Comment: Wait, you mention in your post that you have an instance of `ColorPickerBase` in `ColorPicker`, is this correct or does `ColorPicker` inherit from `ColorPickerBase`? Might be useful posting the whole listing (scrollbars are present so it might not be so bad!)

Comment: You read right, ColorPickerBase is meant as the "main part" of the colorpicker (colorpickerbase is the actual color selector, colorpicker will have additional controls to adjust it). I added the complete class.